# Django TemplateResponse vs render

Tags: django, django-templates

What is the difference between

```
return TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

and

```
return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

Is there any scenario why I should use one of them and not the other?

Comment: Also see docs for [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A `TemplateResponse` delays the rendering of the template until after the view is finished. This allows any [template response middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) to run on the response, and potentially alter the template or the context data before the template is rendered. After the template response middleware has run, the template is rendered, and the normal response middleware is run on the rendered content before the response is returned to the client.

The `render()` shortcut immediately renders the template and returns a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: For more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/template-response/#the-rendering-process

Comment: It's also useful for more than just middleware. For example, you could have a decorator that modifies the context on a view or a test case that checks for the proper template file.

Comment: I might be missing something, but it sort of feels like the template response should be the default, and render should be reserved for lower-level work, like rendering emails, when the middlewares aren't involved. That way, the middlewares would always be able to hook in.