# I just to fetch the updated status

Tags: python, django

Hey i have created a system where after payment it will show PAID. I have a button to proceed to payment but when the payment is successful the button will turn to hidden.Like when the status is paid the button will be hidden

Here is my model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="Unpaid")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Here is my Views.py :

```
def get(self, request, id):
        user_orders = Order.objects.get(pk=id)
        args = {'user_orders': user_orders}
        return render(self.request, 'Home/invoice.html', args)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=request.session['customer']['id'])
        user_orders = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['id'])
        total = user_orders.total
        balance = request.session['customer']['coin']

        if balance >= total:
            balance = balance - total
            customer.coin = balance
            customer.save()

            Order.objects.filter(pk=kwargs['id']).update(
                status='PAID'
            )

            request.session['customer']['coin'] = balance
            request.session.save()

            return redirect('/orders')

        return HttpResponse("Insufficient Balance")
```

Comment: Just make an `If` to show the button when payment status is not "PAID"

Comment: can you give me an sample

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236527/hide-a-html-button-based-on-a-if-condition

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you pass variables into the template, as referenced in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53059318/12467282).

So you might need to alter your view as follows:

```py
# the original one
return redirect('/orders')

# the new one
context = {'payment': 'successful' }
return render(requset,'whatever_template.html', context)
```

And then do something like this in your template:

```html
{% if payment != 'successful' %}
  <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
{% endif %}
```

The logic here is to only show the button if the payment is not successful yet. This is Django's Jinja template syntax (more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/)) that enables functions like conditionals.

This is the most basic answer that I can come up with. If `render` with attributes does not suffice your needs, I will suggest you take a dive into other functions like `HttpResponse` or `TemplateResponse`.

**EDIT** I really think you should use `TemplateResponse` if you want to update the template without refreshing, although I'm not quite sure. You can find a comparison between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838757/12467282) and more examples online.